# How to manage multiple ABI versions with inline namespaces on a large project?

Tags: c++, namespaces, abi

C++11's inline namespaces seem designed to solve the problem of supporting multiple ABI versions in the same C++ header by adding a new namespace with the new version of the API and changing which is inlined by default:

```
inline namespace abi2 {
  int bar(int x);  // New version

  int baz();  // The same
}

namespace abi1 {
  int bar(int x, int y);  // Deprecated

  int baz();  // The same
}
```

Programs that were compiled back when `abi1` was the inlined namespace can still link at runtime to the library once `abi2` is added (as the default for newly-compiled programs). I get all this.

The part that I don't understand is: if I have, say, 200 methods in many header files all in `abi1` and I want to break the ABI by changing a few of them (introducing `abi2`), is there a way to do that without redeclaring (and implementing) all of the methods that did not change between versions (`baz` above) in `abi2`?